# Dockerized Python (Streamlit) app uses wrong folder for python libraries

Tags: python, docker, python-3.6, streamlit

I try to dockerize a Streamlit App. Creating the image works, but when I try to start the app, python seems to try the wrong path for my packages.

The App should run on openshift with python 3.6.

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/redhat-openjdk-18/openjdk18-openshift

USER root

ADD content /

RUN yum -y update \
&&  yum -y --enablerepo "*" install bzip2 \
    python36-pip \
    python36 \
    python36-devel \
    openssl \
 && yum clean all -y

RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages \
    && python3 -m ensurepip
    
ENV PIP_CONFIG_FILE=/opt/pip/pip.conf

RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN python3 -m pip install -r /opt/pip/requirements.txt 

ENV LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8
ENV LANG=en_US.utf-8

RUN useradd -rm -d /home/usdlmod -s /bin/bash -g root -u 1001 usdlmod -p "$(openssl passwd -1 usdlmod)"

RUN chgrp root /etc/passwd && chmod ug+rw /etc/passwd

USER usdlmod

CMD ["python", "-m", "streamlit.cli", "run", "main.py", "--server.port=8080"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

On Openshift I  get the following error: `/usr/bin/python: No module named streamlit`

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Earlier in the question you `RUN python3`, but your final line is `CMD ["python", ...]`.  Does the image wind up with both Python 2.x and 3.x installed, and you're using the wrong one; does changing to `CMD ["python3", ...]` help?

Comment: Sanity check that `streamlit` is in `/opt/pip/requirements.txt`?

Comment: streamlit is in the requirements.txt. I try david maze idea:-)

Comment: thank you david, that solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you both have python 2 and python 3 installed. Changing the cmd to python3 will solve it.

Comment: Based on comments under the question, that seems to have been the issue indeed. But this was a few months ago, so it's a bit late to present it as a question like this now.